# join ZFS/Solaris to windows AD 2003/2008 domain

Tags: active-directory, solaris

I  have a client trying to join his newly updated ZFS/Solaris box to my Windows AD 2003/2008 domain. Here is the command he is using and the error he is getting;

```
Console:
root@xxx:/etc/inet# smbadm join -u USER DOMAIN
After joining DOMAIN the smb service will be restarted automatically.Would you like to continue? [no]: yes
Enter domain password:
Joining DOMAIN ... this may take a minute ...
failed to join DOMAIN: UNSUCCESSFUL
Please refer to the system log for more information.

From /var/adm/messages:
Sep 22 10:12:00 xxx smbd[593]: [ID 702911 daemon.error] smbrdr_exchange[116]: failed (-3)
Sep 22 10:12:01 xxx smbd[593]: [ID 232655 daemon.notice] ldap_modify: Insufficient access
Sep 22 10:12:01 xxx smbd[593]: [ID 898201 daemon.notice] Unable to set the TRUSTED_FOR_DELEGATION userAccountControl flag on the machine account in Active Directory.  Please refer to the Troubleshooting guide for more information.
Sep 22 10:12:01 xxx smbd[593]: [ID 526780 daemon.notice] Failed to establish NETLOGON credential chain
Sep 22 10:12:01 xxx smbd[593]: [ID 871254 daemon.error] smbd: failed joining DOMAIN (UNSUCCESSFUL)
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the credentials that he is using don't have permission to join a machine to AD. Is the user able to join Windows machines? If not, they won't be able to join non-Windows machines.

If you pre-create the computer object in Active Directory, you can delegate the ability to bind a machine to the object by entering the username of the user in the area located below:

[image: New Object dialogue]

Comment: Credentials on the AD object was my first stop. However its all in place. The user account has the appropriate level of access on the object and should be able to add it to the domain. Any other ideas?

Comment: @user95587 What do you mean by "appropriate level of access"? Is the account in the Domain Admins group or not?

Comment: @TomShaw One need not necessarily (nor by default) be a domain admin to join a machine to a domain. This can be changed.

Comment: @user84104 The [Solaris CIFS Service Troubleshooting Guide](http://wiki.genunix.org:8080/wiki/index.php?title=CIFS_Service_Troubleshooting&redirect=no#Joining_a_Domain_Using_an_OU_Admin_Account_.28TRUSTED_FOR_DELEGATION.29) suggests otherwise. I'll defer to you if you know another way, but it's still worth confirming whether user95587 knows about this.

Comment: @Tom that's entirely AD specific and not Solaris specific. The guide likely says that to eliminate permission issues, since it's a troubleshooting guide.

Comment: @MarkM Absolutely. IMHO permission issues have not been eliminated, and are still the most likely cause - thus my request for clarification from user95587. I'm not sure why that should be controversial..

Comment: I didn't say that it wasn't still probably permission issues. What I did say was that there are a lot of other situations that will work without that user being domain admin.

Comment: Sorry for my long silence, other problems took precedence and now I have more information on this problem from the user. To answer Tom's question, no, this user is not in the Domain Admins group. The user, like all our users, has enough privilege on the object to add it to the domain, but no more than that.

Comment: We normally pre-stage objects with the following permissions;
Reset password;
Validated write to DNS host name;
Validated write to service principal name;
Write account restrictions. We have many OS versions in our domain. If this was just a Solaris box, our normal pre-staging would have sufficed.

Comment: However this box is Nexenta (with an open solaris kernel) and will function as shared storage/file space for one of our units. The only other similar objects in our domain are our NetApps, which do indeed require admin/root privilege in the domain.

This Nexenta object wants full admin/root privilege in AD to join the domain. This level of privilege is not allowed by our policy for our users.

We are in the process of discussions with Nexenta to get the specific list of permissions this object needs to support it without root privilege.